# Why is this for loop removing the first one or two characters of a file path?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, cygwin, find

I am trying to find all *.flac files in a directory tree, encode them with ffmpeg, and then output them to a corresponding tree in another location. I am using Cygwin on Windows 10. This is what I have so far:

```
$ find /cygdrive/d/Users/Drew/Music/beets/Music -type f -name '*\.flac' > files
$ while read line; do ffmpeg -i "$line" -f null "$(echo $line | sed 's/\.flac/\.mp3/' | sed 's/Music\/beets/Desktop/')"; done < files
```

The first command has generated a good list of files (that I can tell), but the while loop gives ffmpeg errors every other file due to the leading '/' being trimmed:

```
cygdrive/d/Users/Drew/Music/beets/Music/$uicideboy$/Eternal Grey/06 Uglier.flac: No such file or directory
```

and occasionally another error seemingly randomly when 2 characters are trimmed:

```
Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 'ygdrive/d/Users/Drew/Music/beets/Music/$uicideboy$/Eternal Grey/08 Elysian Fields.flac'
```

Is there some newline problem going on here that I can not detect? Is it something else? Why is this happening?

Comment: Does it work with `read -r`? http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [stackoverflow: When reading a file line by line, I only get to execute ffmpeg on the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584391/when-reading-a-file-line-by-line-i-only-get-to-execute-ffmpeg-on-the-first-line). See also [BashFAQ #89: I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['while read' loop through lines in text file losing characters in Bash script. is FFmpeg line to blame?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088032/while-read-loop-through-lines-in-text-file-losing-characters-in-bash-script-i)