# Why does FFmpeg require nostdin in while loop?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

If I have:

```
for i in *.mov;
do
ffmpeg -y -i $i -c:v copy -c:a copy ${i%%.mov}.mp4
done
```

This runs fine.
But if I run:

```
find . -name "*.ts" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file;
do
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -map 0 "${file%%.ts}_rec.mp4";
done
```

This fails. I need to put in -nostdin.

```
find . -name "*.ts" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file;
do
  ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$file" -c copy -map 0 "${file%%.ts}_rec.mp4";
done
```

The documentation explains that this disables interaction on std input, and is helpful for background processes.

Why is FFmpeg a background process in the second case? Or is there some other issue?

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski. But the reason is still not clear to me. The suggested answer- use `-nostdin`, is also known to me. But the reason why ffmpeg is a background process here, is not clear to me.

Comment: But following your link, I reached this: http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/fixing-stdin-inside-a-redirected-loop/400460. Perhaps this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks man .. i was looking for this (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FFmpeg is not a background process here. It just reads its `stdin`. It might not, but it does. This consumes characters that should go to `read`. In effect you can experience issues like this one:

['while read' loop through lines in text file losing characters in Bash script. is FFmpeg line to blame?](https://superuser.com/q/1088032/432690)

---

The documentation mentions background processes because usually you don’t want *them in particular* to read `stdin`. In your case you don’t want foreground FFmpeg to read its `stdin`.

Comment: *This unjustified "appetite"* --> ffmpeg accepts interactive kbd input during runtime e.g. filter commands or to toggle log verbosity. Press ? to see list of commands.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you. I admit I didn't know this. From now on I consider the appetite justified. :)

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the working loop and the non-working is the | which creates a sub shell.

If I recall correctly, I have solved it by simply using `echo "" | ffmpeg ...`

> From ffmpeg man:
>          -stdin
>              Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless standard input is used as an input. To explicitly
>              disable interaction you need to specify "-nostdin".
>
> ```
>        Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if ffmpeg is in the background process
>        group. Roughly the same result can be achieved with "ffmpeg ... < /dev/null" but it requires a shell.
> ```

`echo "" | ffmpeg` is the same as `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null`

Comment: Could you explain that more fully? The full command perhaps?

Comment: This does not answer the question *Why does FFmpeg require nostdin in while loop?*