# Skipped lines reading series of ffmpeg commands

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal.app

I have a text file that contains these lines:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:44:01 -c copy '01_Myles_Burnyeat_on_Plato.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 00:43:57 -to 01:27:26 -c copy '02_Martha_Nussbaum_on_Aristotle.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 01:27:22 -to 02:10:27 -c copy '03_Anthony_Kenny_on_Medieval_Philosophy.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 02:10:23 -to 02:53:32 -c copy '04_Bernard_Williams_on_Descartes.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 02:53:28 -to 03:37:04 -c copy '05_Anthony_Quinton_on_Spinoza_and_Leibniz.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 03:37:00 -to 04:20:11 -c copy '06_Michael_Ayers_on_Locke_and_Berkeley.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 04:20:07 -to 05:01:26 -c copy '07_John_Passmore_on_Hume.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 05:01:22 -to 05:44:16 -c copy '08_Geoffrey_Warnock_on_Kant.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 05:44:12 -to 06:27:17 -c copy '09_Peter_Singer_on_Hegel_and_Marx.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 06:27:13 -to 07:10:44 -c copy '10_Frederick_Copleston_on_Schopenhauer.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 07:10:40 -to 07:53:44 -c copy '11_J_P_Stern_on_Nietzsche.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 07:53:40 -to 08:39:17 -c copy '12_Hubert_Dreyfus_on_Husserl_and_Heidegger.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 08:39:13 -to 09:20:06 -c copy '13_Sidney_Morgenbesser_on_the_American_Pragmatists.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 09:20:02 -to 10:02:14 -c copy '14_A_J_Ayer_on_Frege_Russell_and_Modern_Logic.mp4'

ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -i TGP.mp4 -ss 10:02:10 -to 10:45:21 -c copy '15_John_Searle_on_Wittgenstein.mp4'
```

When I run a one-liner in Terminal:

while read -r line; do eval "$line"; done < commands.txt

The files output are:

01_Myles_Burnyeat_on_Plato.mp4
03_Anthony_Kenny_on_Medieval_Philosophy.mp4
05_Anthony_Quinton_on_Spinoza_and_Leibniz.mp4
07_John_Passmore_on_Hume.mp4
09_Peter_Singer_on_Hegel_and_Marx.mp4
11_J_P_Stern_on_Nietzsche.mp4
13_Sidney_Morgenbesser_on_the_American_Pragmatists.mp4

Why are half the files skipped? Is it because every new command N goes back a bit, prior to the endpoint of the previous one?

For example, line one ends at 44:01, and line two starts at 43:57.  But so what?  Doesn't my "-ss" at the start of each "rewind" the "head" the the beginning again?

UPDATE: I changed the times and still, every other line is being skipped (i.e., the output is the same as above). Now I’m totally lost. (Yes, they are newlines and not CRs.)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why do you terribly overcomplicate with that `read` and that dangerous `eval` stuff? It should be simply `sh commands.txt`.

Comment: `ffmpeg` reads from stdin, so it's stealin part of the input file. See [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089), ["`while read` loop through lines in text file losing characters in Bash script. is FFmpeg line to blame?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1088032/while-read-loop-through-lines-in-text-file-losing-characters-in-bash-script-i), and ["Why does FFmpeg require nostdin in while loop?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1492507/why-does-ffmpeg-require-nostdin-in-while-loop)