# Works from terminal prompt. How to get bash script working?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

using:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)
and
`script --version`
script from util-linux 2.34

These commands are working from a terminal prompt:

`script /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat ; # Log file start.`
`script --version ;                    # 2.34 version number, for clarity.`
`bash /media/x/usb_stick/clamscan.sh ; # virus scan script.`
`ls ;                                  # example of other commands to Log.`
`exit ;                                # Log file end.`
`cat /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat ;    # review Log file in colour.`

How to get above terminal prompt commands working
from a bash script?

Purpose of above commands?
To make a colour Log file of a scan. ( Clam AntiVirus: Scanner 0.103.6 )
Colour Log means not text but text with colour as you see it from the prompt.
Colour Log file = /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat

Problem:
bash script stops after first line:
script /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat ;              # Log file start.
saying:
`Script started, file is /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat`

Above commands work from terminal prompt.
How to automate?
How to get above commands working in a bash script?

--

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

Lines in a shell script do not simulate keyboard input. Each statement is a command that must finish before the next is run, and the entire thing runs in the context of the parent shell.

In an interactive shell you can type `script mylog`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, this gives you *another* (inner) shell and then you can type e.g. `ls`<kbd>Enter</kbd> which executes `ls` in the inner shell. Eventually you can exit the inner shell by typing `exit`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. When `script` sees the other shell exits, it exits. When the original (outer) shell sees `script` exits, it continues: it shows you the prompt and reads what you type. The next command (e.g. `cat mylog`) will be executed in the original shell.

As long as `script` runs, the outer shell waits and does not try to read from the terminal (in general: from stdin; in case of an interactive shell stdin is often the terminal). `script` reads from the terminal and relays input to the inner shell.

The same sequence of commands in a script being executed will make the shell executing the script run `script mylog` and wait for it to exit, just like in the case of interactive usage. And just like in the case of interactive usage, the inner shell will run commands relayed by `script`, i.e. whatever `script` reads from its stdin (which is usually the terminal). The important difference is: the outer shell reads code from the regular file (i.e. not from stdin), but the inner shell can only get code from stdin. The inner shell has no access to the script.

You claim your script stops after `script /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat`. It does not stop. It waits for `script` to exit; and `script` waits for the inner shell to exit; and the inner shell waits for you to type something. The prompt from the inner shell most likely looks exactly like the prompt from the interactive shell you started from, so you may think the whole script has exited. No, it has not; you're in the inner shell inside `script` inside the outer shell (interpreting your script file) and the original interactive shell is even more outer. Now if you type `exit` then the script will continue and commands you intended for the inner shell will be executed by the shell interpreting the script, including the `exit` line (`cat …` will never be executed).

---

#### Flawed "solution"

By providing the script via stdin of the outer shell, you can kinda simulate keyboard input. Like this:

```
# But don't.
bash <./the_script
```

This `bash` will read code from its stdin and when it invokes `script …`, the tool will inherit the stdin, so by reading its stdin it will also read from the file. This method is flawed because:

- `bash` can and sometimes will (and in some cases must) read the file beyond `script …` before it invokes `script`. In effect `script` may read the file (i.e. the inner shell may get the code) starting from a point you don't expect. After it exits, the shell interpreting the script will execute already read code it shouldn't have read in the first place.
- Even if `bash` reads exactly what you hope for, `script` will probably read beyond `exit` (in our case it will read the `cat …` line). The inner shell will get `exit` and it will exit as expected, but the outer shell won't see what `script` has read excessively (`cat …` won't be executed at all; neither the inner shell nor the outer shell will see it).

---

#### Solution: here document

It's way better to run `the_script` normally. Inside it you can run `script` with redirected stdin. This example `the_script` uses a here document for redirection:

```
#!/bin/sh
script mylog <<EOF
ls
date
EOF
cat mylog
```

Now `script` can read from the here document only (and you don't need `exit`, the sole end of the here document should be enough). Note if instead of (or alongside) `ls` or `date` you had a command that reads from its stdin (e.g. another `script` or [`ffmpeg`](https://superuser.com/q/1088032/432690)) then the problem of some tool reading too much would appear, like in the flawed "solution" above; it would be about reading too much from the here document, not from the entire script, but still.

If what you want to run inside `script` does not read from stdin, or if you properly redirect stdin of whatever wants to read, then a here document may be a good solution.

---

#### Solution: `script --command`

Another solution is to provide code (to run in the inner shell) as an argument to `script`. From `man 1 script`:

> `-c, --command command`
> Run the `command` rather than an interactive shell. This makes it easy for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.

It's not explicitly stated, but `command` is interpreted as shell code (i.e. not necessarily a single executable). Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
script mylog -c '
  ls
  date
'
cat mylog
```

Note the inner shell interpreting `ls; date` is not an interactive shell. It won't print prompts and probably your aliases won't work.

---

#### Final note

There are other tools that give you a shell or a shell-like interface, or just read from stdin for whatever reason. Imagine instead of `script …` you have `bash`, `ssh user@server`, `python3` or even `cat`. If you invoke any of it from a shell script, don't expect the next line(s) of the script to get to the tool. The mechanism is exactly like explained, it's not specific to `script`. Our solution using a here document is universal. Our solution using `script -c` is obviously specific to `script`, but other tools may support a similar way to provide code/input as a command line argument (e.g. `bash -c code`, `ssh user@server code`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Kamil's answer ...

`#!/bin/sh`
`script /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat -c '`
    `clear                                 # reduce scroll-back text / screens.`
    `bash /media/x/usb_stick/clamscan.sh   # virus scan script.`
    `echo "Ctrl-Shift-UParrow              # keyboard shortcut scroll-back reminder."`
`'`
`cat /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat`

Kamil's answer of
the original (outer) shell versus inner shell ...
reminds me of
Star Trek The Next Generation Professor Moriarty
Elementary, Dear Data

Professor Moriarty Call For the Holodeck's Arch
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msjQKkkW2Wo

Captain Picard...
Computer End Program.
...
Computer End Program.
Computer ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To add clarity, the question ```How to get bash script working?``` is 
stated in above bash script, specifically, the 4 characters ```-c '``` 
in the command  
```script /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat -c '``` and 
then later 1 character ```'``` to close it off thus above script deals with 
the issue of the original (outer) shell versus inner shell via 
script version 2.34 and also to get a colour Log on screen 
then cat the Log file meaning ```cat /home/x/Desktop/clamlog2.cat``` or 
Kamil's answer (e.g. ```cat mylog``` ).