# How to "save the state" when reading from a file with `read`?

Tags: bash, shell, redirection

I have a `file` with 3 lines:

```
1
2
3
```

When doing `read a < file`, then doing `echo $a`, the result is always the same, which is `1`.

I want `read` to continue from where it left. How can I do that? If it's not possible, how come it works when `read` is used in a `while read; do some_stuff; done < file`?

Comment: `bash` has some complex rules with execution scopes and subshells, etc. that are probably not worth getting too deep into; if you need that level of complexity these days you might be better off with Python or something similar.  It's probably because with `while read a; do echo $a; done < file` the `< file` applies to the entire `while`/`done` block, not just a single command as in `read $a < file`.

Comment: I wanted to use Bash because my script uses lot of commands. You are right a modern language might be easier even if you have to call a library to execute a system command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `read a < file` opens the `file` anew and reads it from the beginning. On the other hand `while read; do some_stuff; done < file` opens the `file` once and the entire loop ([including `some_stuff`](https://superuser.com/a/421707/432690)) can read from it.

Bash allows you to assign an additional file descriptor. Then `read -u` can read from it without reopening:

```bsh
exec 17<file   # open
read -u 17 a
echo "$a"
read -u 17 a
echo "$a"
read -u 17 a
echo "$a"
exec 17>&-     # close
```

Here `17` was chosen almost arbitrarily, it has no special meaning. Bash can tell you the maximum number of open file descriptors, invoke `ulimit -n`. In my Debian 10 it's `1024`. I could choose almost any non-negative integer less than that, but in your Bash it may be e.g. `512`, so it's safer to stick to "low" numbers. `0`, `1` and `2` are stdin, stdout and stderr respectively; [`255` is used by Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729906/10765659). Technically one can redirect them but in this case you want to pick an unused number. [Bash can do it for you](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections):

> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form `{varname}`. In this case, for each redirection operator except `>&-` and `<&-`, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than `10` and assign it to `{varname}`. If `>&-` or `<&-` is preceded by `{varname}`, the value of `varname` defines the file descriptor to close. If `{varname}` is supplied, the redirection persists beyond the scope of the command, allowing the shell programmer to manage the file descriptor himself.

The following example uses this method:

```bsh
exec {myfd}<file   # open
read -u "$myfd" a
echo "$a"
read -u "$myfd" a
echo "$a"
read -u "$myfd" a
echo "$a"
exec {myfd}>&-     # close
unset myfd
```

This way it's impossible to pick a number that is already in use; you may know nothing about `0`, `1`, `2` and `255` being special. It's still possible to pick a name already in use, so the issue converges to naming and managing variables.

Comment: does 17 hold a special meaning ? can you use any number (except from 0 1 2 as they  are stds) ?

Comment: @confused_bash_user Answer expanded.